# VBA SQL query Type mismatch

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I want to add field in access table with below coding but it is showing an error as type mismatch. Please advise as to what went wrong.

```
With Acon
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Sheet1.Range("V3").value & filen & ".accdb"
    .Open
End With

Set Rs = Acon.Execute("ALTER TABLE Sheet1 ADD COLUMN [" & [Other Trainer] & "] number;")
```

Comment: Is it intentional that you used + after data source rather than &? You can't add a string to a number.

Comment: where is the type mismatch?

Comment: Set Rs = Acon.Execute("ALTER TABLE Sheet1 ADD COLUMN [" & [Other Trainer] & "] number